# Sign PDF with Itext5 got error "PdfPKCS7 can't access void org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERNull.<init>()" in Quarkus

Tags: kotlin, pdf, bouncycastle, quarkus, sign

I'm trying to sign pdf file using itext5 in a quarkus application but I'm receiving an error that I can't understand.
Below the code I try to sign my pdf with. I upgraded my dependency for bouncyCastle but another error has been shown

Here's the code:

```java
 @Throws(GeneralSecurityException::class, IOException::class, DocumentException::class)
    fun sign(
        src: String? //The path of the pdf file that needs to be signed
        , dest: String? //The path of the pdf file where the seal is signed
        , chain: Array<Certificate> //Certificate chain
        , pk: PrivateKey? //Signature private key
        , digestAlgorithm: String? //Abstract Algorithm name, such as SHA-1
        , provider: String? //Key algorithm provider, can be null
        , subfilter: CryptoStandard? //Digital signature format, itext has 2 types
        , reason: String? //The reason for the signature, displayed in the pdf signature attribute, Just fill in
        , location: String?
    ) {
        //The steps below are fixed, just follow the

        //instructions , there is nothing to explain //Creating the reader and the stamper, start pdfreader
        val reader = PdfReader(src)
        //Target file output stream
        val os = FileOutputStream(dest)
        //Create a signature tool PdfStamper. If the last boolean parameter
        //false, the pdf file is only allowed to be signed once and signed multiple times. If the last one is valid
        //true, the pdf can be signed and verified The signature tool can identify whether the document is modified after each signature.
        val stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\u0000', null, true)
        //Get the digital signature attribute object and set the attributes of the digital signature
        val appearance = stamper.signatureAppearance
        appearance.reason = reason
        appearance.location = location
        //Set the location of the signature, the page number, and the name of the signature domain. When multiple signatures are added, the pre-name of the signature cannot be the same.
        //The position of the signature is the position coordinate of the stamp relative to the pdf page. The origin is the lower left corner of the pdf page.
        //4.The two parameters are: the lower left corner of the stamp x, the lower left corner of the stamp y, the upper right corner of the stamp x, the upper right corner of the stamp y
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(Rectangle(200f, 200f, 300f, 300f), 1, "sig1")
        //Read the stamp image, this image is the image of the itext package
        val image: Image = Image.getInstance("path_to_image")
        appearance.signatureGraphic = image
        appearance.certificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED
        //Set the display mode of the stamp. The following option is to display only the stamp (there are other modes, and the stamp and signature description can be displayed together)
        appearance.renderingMode = RenderingMode.GRAPHIC

        //The itext here provides 2 interfaces for signatures, which can be implemented by yourself. I will focus on this implementation later.
        //Digest algorithm
        val digest: ExternalDigest = BouncyCastleDigest()
        //Signature algorithm
        val signature: ExternalSignature = PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, null)
        //Call itext signature method to complete pdf signature
        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter)
    }
```

These are the dependencies I'm using after I upgraded the bouncyCastle.

```xml
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.13.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.70</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.70</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk15on -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.70</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this is the stacktrace error of the problem I have occurred.

```
2022-01-20 16:29:37,480 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) HTTP Request to /api/pdf failed, error id: 0c85cbe3-7a9b-4899-a00e-ed94d9f8be37-1: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7 tried to access private method 'void org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERNull.<init>()' (com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7 and org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERNull are in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @1bd4fdd)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:105)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:359)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:135)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:90)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:543)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Are you sure iText 5.5.13.2 was developed for BC 1.70?

Comment: I was receiving another error when I put a lower version for BC nut how can I know which version corresponds to the itext version?

Comment: Looking at the [iText 5.5.13.2 pom.xml](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/f9350ff7194da228a650be9b649389103a769ec9/itext/pom.xml) one sees that it is built with BouncyCastle 1.66 as dependency.

Comment: thank you for you proposition , in the end i switched to itext7 and there was no problem with BC

Comment: iText 7 is actively maintained while iText 5 is at its end-of-life. Thus, it is to be expected that iText 7 can utilize more current BC versions while iText 5 cannot.

Comment: btw I got this error when using openPdf v1.2.3java7 + BC 1.70 - I switched to the 1.2.21 version of openPdf (alas it only works with Java 8+ - I thought it would work with Java 7 at the time) to stop it from happening. the real cause is that in BC at some point after v. 1.47, DERNull() constructor became package private and got deprecated in favour of DERNull.INSTANCE static constant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the version of com.itextpdf:sign to 7.2.5.